# Powerwashing Chromebook duplicates the device entry in the Family Link app

Tags: google-family-link, chromebook

I powerwash (factory reset) my Chromebook 4 times, then 4 devices showed up in the Family Link app on Android. It is just 1 physical device, but 4 devices coming up in software.

Any ways to resolve this?

Comment: is that one device for each power wash?

Comment: yes, one device for each power wash